# How to get specific number of elements in an array dynamically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of something and I need to get the three first items of this array. The thing is, sometimes the array is empty, sometimes it has more than 3 items. I don't know how to do it so I get either 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 items depending of the size of the array. I tried to do something with a range but I'm out of range when the array is empty or has less than 3 items:

```
let items = arrayOfItems.items?[0...3]
```

I'm thinking about a switch but I guess there something better to do.

Comment: `let upToFirstThreeItems = Array(allItems.prefix(3))`?

Comment: It's exactly the anser I needed, yes. Thanks!